# What is actually provided for by the "automatic additional driver" that a spouse gets in a rental car agreement in Oregon?

Tags: insurance

I have seen many sources that mention states (such as Oregon) that automatically allow spouses to be additional drivers on rental vehicles, including this one from Enterprise Rent-A-Car itself:

https://www.enterprise.com/en/help/faqs/additional-driver.html

"Note: State law in California, Illinois, Missouri, Nevada, Oregon and Wisconsin allows a spouse to be an automatic authorized driver provided they meet minimum age and driver's license requirements"

But upon trying to rent a car from Dollar, I was told that spouses had to pay the additional driver fee, like anyone else.

So I tried to find the law, and found:

https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/646A.140

But this only allows spouses to automatically be added to the CDW for rental cars.  As far as I can tell, this means if you don't get the CDW, then the spouse isn't automatically added, and the if the spouse gets into an accident, the rental contract could be voided, which could mean that the personal driver's insurance they may have may not actually cover the accident.

Am I reading this right, and all the sources about automatic additional drivers on the net (including Enterprise) are wrong??